# react native asks to change kotlin version

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

when i want to debug my app on my android phone using react-native start i get this error:

> {...} was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary
> version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

Even changing kotlin version in build.gradle doesnt change this error (even expected version info)

i was trying with addding these lines to build gradle

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'

ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'

ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
```

nothing changes...

JVM VERSION 20, gradle 8.1